# Add or Subtract Fields on a Create Razor Page and Display Result on Page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, calculated-field

Let's say I have a Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Test.Model
{
    public class Balance
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id
        [Display(Name = "Invoice Amount")] 
        public int? InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Payment Amount")] 
        public int? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
        public int Balance {get; set; }
        {
             InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount
        }
    }
}
```

I don't need to store the Balance in the database, as I can always calculate it, but how would I display it on a create page when someone is creating a record and inputting the InvoiceAmount and PaymentAmount?

How would I do that BEFORE I have submitted the form and committed the InvoiceAmount and PaymentAmount to the database?

And what if they change either the InvoiceAmount or PaymentAmount after entering them? How can I have the Balance change on the fly like that? I'm thinking both the InvoiceAmount and the PaymentAmount would need some type of event (is that the right word - I'm not a programmer) tied to them?

I've searched here, but haven't found anything explained that has been for a Create page. Only fields that are already bound and being reported on.

Looking to understand how this works using this very basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't need to store the Balance in the database, as I can always
> calculate it,

If you want to have a property in your model class without being stored in database, you can use the `[NotMapped]` attribute to ignore the property.

> but how would I display it on a create page when someone is creating
> a record and inputting the InvoiceAmount and PaymentAmount?
>
> How would I do that BEFORE I have submitted the form and committed the
> InvoiceAmount and PaymentAmount to the database?
>
> And what if they change either the InvoiceAmount or PaymentAmount
> after entering them?

You define the calculation in the model, this way requires server-side interaction or a page refresh which can update the value. To achieve real-time updates of the `Balance` field, you can use Jquery to listen for changes in the `InvoiceAmount` and `PaymentAmount` input fields.

A working demo you could follow:

Model

```
public class Balance
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Invoice Amount")]
    public int? InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Payment Amount")]
    public int? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] // This will ensure that Balance is not created in the database
    public int BalanceAmount { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model Balance
<form>
    Invoice Amount: <input asp-for="InvoiceAmount"><br>
    Payment Amount: <input asp-for="PaymentAmount"><br>
    Balance: <span id="balanceDisplay">0</span><br>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function updateBalance() {
                var invoiceAmount = parseInt($('#InvoiceAmount').val()) || 0;
                var paymentAmount = parseInt($('#PaymentAmount').val()) || 0;

                var balance = invoiceAmount - paymentAmount;
                $('#balanceDisplay').text(balance);
            }

            $('#InvoiceAmount, #PaymentAmount').on('input', updateBalance);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Update:

> I could not get this to work in my own app until I added
> id="InvoiceAmount" to <input asp=for"Balance.InvoiceAmount"> and
> likewise id="PaymentAmount" to

The tag helper `asp-for` will generate the id and name attribute by default, the value of your tag helper is `Balance.InvoiceAmount`, it will generate the `id="Balance_InvoiceAmount"` and `name="Balance.InvoiceAmount"`. Any way, your solution to define id to override the tag hepler generated id is also a good solution.

Comment: Thanks, Rena. I could not get this to work in my own app until I added id="InvoiceAmount" to <input asp=for"Balance.InvoiceAmount"> and likewise id="PaymentAmount" to <input asp-for="Balance.PaymentAmount"> I also had to change .text(balance) to .val(balance). The only issue I have now is that my InvoiceAmount and PaymentAmount were actually public decimal? not public Int? How do I get the fields to return the 2 decimal places? Is there a parseDecimal or similar? UPDATE: I discovered parseFloat seems to work.

Comment: Hi @MelB, I have updated the answer and explain to your confusion.   For you do not share the whole code and your shared code it type of int. for this issue: `I also had to change .text(balance) to .val(balance}` ,  I think you may check my answer carefully, I use the `span`, of course it needs `.text()`to get the value.  My answer is just an sample for how to use js to achieve your requirement, but it cannot be copied and pasted to resolve your issue because I do not know how is your page design.  Any way I think my answer helps you resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, it does resolve my error and yes, it was my mistake for not including 'decimal' in my example. Thank you!